# What is the difference between local_setup.bash and setup.bash

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, build, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS2, we always source the `local_setup.bash` while working with the original parent workspace. Now lets say if i create an overlay workspace and create my own package, then while trying to build it, shall i source the `local_setup.bash` or the `setup.bash`.

My observation : if i start a new terminal and try these commands :

```
cd ~/ros2_overlay_ws/
source install/ local_setup.bash
ament build
```

This gives me an error stating `ament: command not found`

But if i source the `setup.bash file` instead, the build is successfull. wehereas i thought `local_setup.bash` file is used for sourcing the current variables to the current path. So it sould have built with the `local_setup.bash` Could anyone please clear out the differences ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292566/what-is-the-difference-between-local_setup.bash-and-setup.bash/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-29

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer the actual question first:

- The `local_setup.<ext>` script sets up the environment for all package in the prefix path where that script is. It doesn't include any parent workspaces.
- The `setup.<ext>` script on the other hand sources the `local_setup.<ext>` script for all workspaces which were sourced in the environment when this workspace was built. And then it also sources the sibling `local_setup.<ext>` script.

What does that mean:

- If you want to source the first workspace (e.g. `/opt/ros/ardent`) it doesn't make any difference because that workspace doesn't have any parent workspaces.
- If you have built your own workspace `~/ws` after sourcing `/opt/ros/ardent` you can do either of the following:

  - Source `~/ws/install/setup.<ext>` to setup the environment to include paths from `/opt/ros/ardent` as well as `~/ws/install`.
  - That is the same as if you would source `/opt/ros/ardent/(local_)setup.<ext>` first and then `~/ws/install/local_setup.<ext>`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fredBeauj](https://answers.ros.org/users/59109/fredbeauj/) on 2021-06-02**:
In case someone needs it: essentially the same info from the [colcon documentation](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/environment.html#workspace-level)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should source `setup.bash` of the original (underlay) workspace before building the overlay workspace.   Once you have built the overlay workspace, you should be able to source `setup.bash`, which will chain the underlay and the overlay together.

From the ament documentation:

> The different shell scripts in the
> root of the install space are
> generated by the ament tool. The
> local_setup.* files only iterate over
> all packages in the install space (by
> reading the list of packages in the
> ament index) and source their package
> specific setup files. The setup.*
> files also consider workspaces outside
> of this install space (by reading the
> list of parent_prefixp_path in the
> ament index) and source them before
> the local_setup.* files.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-29**:
Once you have built the overlay workspace, you should be able to source setup.bash, which will chain the underlay and the overlay together.

Did you mistype it here, i would be able to source `local_setup.bash` after building the overlay space ?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2018-05-29**:
If you source `local_setup.bash` of the overlay, it will only consider the packages available in the overlay when adding to the environment.  `setup.bash` will source the underlay and then the overlay, giving you an environment with both workspaces in it.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-29**:
@mjccarroll yes exactly this is what i meant. But in this case why should i use `setup.bash` to source my overlay space ? this should be possible with `local_setup.bash`

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2018-05-29**:
`local_setup.sh` exclusively sources the overlay, you will not have any other packages visible from the other workspace.  My understanding is that this is not your desired behavior?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-29**:
yes,in my case it is the other way round happening which is a bit confusing.

**Comment by [felixf4xu](https://answers.ros.org/users/120001/felixf4xu/) on 2023-07-17**:
@mjccarroll I'm confused by your wording of "overlay" and "underlay".